# Example of a non-measurable $A$ set such that $\mu_{*}(A)=\mu^{*}(A^{c})=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Prove that there exists a non-measurable  $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that  $$\mu_{\ast}(A\cap E)=0 \quad \text{y} \quad \mu^{\ast}(A\cap E)=\mu(E)$$
> for all set measurable $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$.

**My approach:**  Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\mu_{*}(A)=\mu_{*}(A^{c})=0$$
so, we have $A$ is non-measurable set. Indeed, suppose that $A$ is measurable, so $A^{c}$ is also measurbale and since that $\mathbb{R}=A\cup A^{c}$, so we have $$+\infty=\mu(\mathbb{R})=\mu(A)+\mu(A^{c})=\mu_{*}(A)+\mu_{*}(A^{c})=0 \quad  !!$$
So, $A$ is non-measurable set.

Now, we need to prove that if $E$ is measurable with $\mu(E)>0$, so we have $$\mu_{*}(A\cap E)=0\quad \mu^{*}(A\cap E)=\mu(E)$$
Now, since that $\mu_{*}(A^{c})=0 \implies \mu^{*}(A\cap E)=\mu(E)$.
Finally, since that $A\cap E\subset A \implies \mu_{*}(A\cap E)=\mu_{*}(A)=0$

**Is my prove correct?**
**Should I add something else to my prove?**
**I still have to prove that such a set $A$ exists, correct? How could I prove that?**

---

**Here:** $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $\mu_{*}$ is inner measure, $\mu^{*}$ is outer measure and measure it means Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Did you mean to have $\mu_{\ast}(A^c) = 0$? If $\mu^{\ast}(A^c) = 0$, then, since Lebesgue measure is complete, it follows that $A^c$ is Lebesgue measurable (a null set), and consequently $A$ is measurable too (and of full measure, so $\mu_{\ast}(A) = \mu(A) = +\infty$).

Comment: Yes, I have a typo. I corrected.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now, I need to prove that $A$ there exists, correct? How can I prove that part?

Comment: The implication "$\mu_{\ast}(A^c) = 0 \implies \mu^{\ast}(A\cap E) = \mu(E)$" could do with some elaboration. Then you have correctly (modulo one typo where you wrote measur**ba**le instead of measurable) shown that such an $A$ works. (And on the other hand, only such $A$ work.) Thus indeed, what remains is to show the existence of such an $A$. How to prove that? What sort of nonmeasurable sets do you know?

Comment: I was trying to prove the existence of that set, but it's difficult for me.

Comment: My [6 February 2006 sci.math essay on Bernstein sets](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) should be helpful. Note the follow-up correction to one of the statements that appears in the post just below this essay-post.